# How to make the mini image & description container located at the bottom or end of the navbar / header?

Tags: html, css

How to place the `ui-thumbnails ui-content` container at the bottom, lower than the`navbar` or `header` without leaving the container outside.

As you can see the design aspect where the mini images are and, the description this container leaves a space at the bottom on the design of the background image of the `navbar` you can see in the following complete code:

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: Ubuntu;
 font-size: 15px; /*0.9rem;*/
 line-height: 1.6rem;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 font-family: Ubuntu;
 font-size: 1.0rem;
 line-height: 1.6rem;
 color: #363535;
 background-color:#f5f5f5;
}

/************MENU NAVEGATION******************/
.navbar{
 background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(https://i.imgur.com/NU3T1ef.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 height: 800px;
 width: 100%;
 color: #333;
}
.nav-club {
 padding: 0.3em;
 height: 60px;
 width: 80%;
 background: #fff;
}

.club-site {
 display: inline-block;
}
.club-site h4 {
 color: #267788;
 font-size: 1.1rem;
 line-height: 5rem;
}
.nav {
 background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(58, 134, 68, 0.9), rgba(86, 184, 98, 0.72)), url(https://i.imgur.com/VTrnpmb.png);
 background-position: center bottom;
 width: 100%;
 height: 4.5rem;
 background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
 height: 6rem;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0;
 position: relative;
}

.logo img {
 max-height: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}
.navigation {
 padding-left: 17rem;
 float: left;
 color: #000;
}

.navigation ul li {
 padding: 1em;
 display: inline-block;
}


/**********GALLERY**********/
img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
.gallery {
 width: 90%;
 height: 85%;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.ui-big-images {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: flex;
 /*flex-direction: column-reverse;*/
}
.ui-big-image {
 width: 100%;
 margin-right: -100%;
}
.ui-big-image img {
 -o-object-fit: cover;
 object-fit: cover;
 -o-object-position: center 30%;
 object-position: center 30%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
}
.ui-thumbnails {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #fff;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
 -webkit-box-direction: normal;
 flex-direction: row;
 -webkit-box-pack: start;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 -webkit-box-align: center;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 0 1rem;
 padding-top: .5rem;
 padding-right: 45%;
 padding-right: calc( 45% + .5rem);
}
.ui-thumbnail {
 display: block;
 margin-right: .5rem;
 padding: .5rem 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-cuticle {
 background-color: #D4A12D;
 /*position: absolute;*/
 bottom: 0;
 height: .25rem;
 width: 100%;
}
.ui-thumbnail>img {
 width: auto;
}
.ui-content {
 position: absolute;
 width: 40%;
 right: 5%;
 bottom: 0;
}
.ui-articles {
 background: #493e56;
 color: white;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-align: stretch;
 align-items: stretch;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.ui-article {
 padding: 1.5rem;
 width: 100%;
 margin-right: -100%;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 -webkit-box-direction: normal;
 flex-direction: column;
 -webkit-box-pack: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
.ui-paragraph {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: .7rem;
 line-height: 1.7;
}
.ui-nav {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 100%;
 background: inherit;
}
.ui-nav button {
 display: unset !important;
 background: #493e56;
 border: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
 padding: .5em;
 width: 2em;
 color: #FFF;
 font-family: monospace;
 -webkit-transition: inherit;
 transition: inherit;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
 transition-duration: 300ms;
}
.ui-nav button:hover,
.ui-nav button:focus {
 background: #D4A12D;
 outline: none;
}
.ui-nav button:active {
 outline: none;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(0.25em);
 transform: translateY(0.25em);
 -webkit-transition-duration: 100ms;
 transition-duration: 100ms;
}
.ui-heading {
 margin: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
 font-size: 1rem;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.ui-heading:before {
 content: 'Animator';
 font-size: .5rem;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: .5rem;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}
/* ---------------------------------- */
.ui-big-image {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
 transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.ui-big-image.show {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
 transform: translateX(0);
}
.ui-big-image img {
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
 transform: scale(0.8);
}
.ui-big-image[data-active]~.ui-big-image {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
 transform: translateX(100%);
}
.ui-big-image[data-active] {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
 transform: translateX(0%);
}
.ui-big-image[data-active] img {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1);
}
/* ---------------------------------- */
.ui-article {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
 transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.ui-article.show {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
 transform: translateX(0);
}
.ui-article:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #D4A12D;
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
 transition-duration: 0.35s;
 z-index: 1;
}
.ui-article.show:before {
 opacity: 0;
}
.ui-article[data-active]~.ui-article {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
 transform: translateX(100%);
}
.ui-article[data-active] {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
 transform: translateX(0%);
}
.ui-article[data-active]:before {
 opacity: 0;
}
/* ---------------------------------- */
.ui-thumbnail>img {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
 filter: grayscale(100%);
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
 transition-duration: 0.35s;
}
.ui-thumbnail:active>img {
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
 transform: scale(0.9);
 -webkit-transition-duration: 100ms;
 transition-duration: 100ms;
}
.ui-thumbnail:focus {
 outline: none;
}
.ui-cuticle {
 display: none;
}
.ui-cuticle.show {
 display: block;
}
.ui-thumbnail[data-active]>img,
.ui-thumbnail:hover>img {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
 filter: grayscale(0%);
}
.ui-thumbnail[data-active] .ui-cuticle {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="navbar">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="maximum">

      <div class="nav clear">
       <div class="logo">
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery" data-state="0">
       <div class="ui-big-images">
        <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="0">
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=1005" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="1">
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=804" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="2">
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=838" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="3">
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=832" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="4">
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=836" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="5">
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=823" alt="" />
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="ui-thumbnails">
        <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="0">
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=1005" alt="" />
         <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="1">
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=804" alt="" />
         <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="2">
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=838" alt="" />
         <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="3">
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=832" alt="" />
         <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="4">
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=836" alt="" />
         <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="5">
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=823" alt="" />
         <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="ui-content">
        <nav class="ui-nav">
         <button id="prev" tabindex="-1" title="Previous">&lt;</button>
         <button id="next" tabindex="-1" title="Next">&gt;</button>
        </nav>
        <div class="ui-articles">
         <article class="ui-article" data-key="0">
          <h2 class="ui-heading">Stephen Shaw</h2>
          <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae cupiditate assumenda nemo delectus totam atque quas suscipit dicta.</p>
         </article>
         <article class="ui-article" data-key="1">
          <h2 class="ui-heading">David Khourshid</h2>
          <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod sapiente soluta iusto molestias ullam. </p>
         </article>
         <article class="ui-article" data-key="2">
          <h2 class="ui-heading">Coding Compadre</h2>
          <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
         </article>
         <article class="ui-article" data-key="3">
          <h2 class="ui-heading">Boolean Buddy</h2>
          <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. </p>
         </article>
         <article class="ui-article" data-key="4">
          <h2 class="ui-heading">Animation Amigo</h2>
          <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias exercitationem voluptatibus</p>
         </article>
         <article class="ui-article" data-key="5">
          <h2 class="ui-heading">Keyframe Companion</h2>
          <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae soluta reprehenderit, ut doloribus corrupti</p>
         </article>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I have tried to solve using the developer console by adding and removing different types of styles but without obtaining results.

What I want to achieve is to show the container of the mini images and, description `ui-thumbnails ui-content` that are always shown at the bottom at the end without overflowing from the`navbar` or `header` for example:

[image]

And in responsive

[image]

Comment: why is the footer inside the header?

Comment: @MatanSanbira I can't understand, the added design is just the design of the hedader, where the navigation bar is in conjunction with an image gallery. This is the design that is required :)

Comment: @MatanSanbira The green navigation bar is where the navigation menu is going to be displayed, that is not the footer, it is just the header design, nothing more friendly.

Comment: the page scrolls down to more content or is it a one-page app?

Comment: @MatanSanbira Sure friend there is more content under the header, but as the problem I only present in the header so do not add more. It’s just a responsive website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you'r result is supposed to look like. If i get it correctly your trying to bring the info with the mini images on the same level at the end of your Hero img. So for the moment you have `ui-thumbnails` and `ui-content` as two different elements positioned absolute to your hero img. 
I'd put both of them into a wrapper div, wich then should set the position absolute to your hero img. so ui-thumbnails and ui-content is inside the same div. Then give ui-thumbails and ui-content the wanted width. And also add a max-height to your images. This way Your info should be on the same level and you can adjust the position by grabbing the wrapper div.

To make it overflow your hero you should make the background of the wrapper div transparent and scale the bottom property up or down in your inspect, where ever your want.